# remove/update notification from lock screen

Tags: ios, uikit

- I use UILocalNotification to show alerts.
- I need to show two alerts 2 hours apart.
- Right now, my code displays two different notifications on lock screen.
- Assume, alerts/notifs were not touched by user during this period.

Is it possible for me to

- Either remove the first shown notification from lock screen
- Or update the first notification with the contents of second alert/notifcation.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, you cannot modify a `UILocalNotification` once it has been scheduled.

To dismiss an already fired `UILocalNotification`, try calling the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`
 and then re-add those that were not yet fired.